# API issues with the JS version of bittrix

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, node-modules

I am using the website code and still getting `invalid_signatures`, why so, any clue?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/hmac-sha512.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var content = "";
    var contentHash = CryptoJS.SHA512(content).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    document.getElementById('hash').value = contentHash;
    var method = 'GET';
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    var uri = 'https://api.bittrex.com/v3/balances';
    var preSign = [timestamp, uri, method, contentHash].join('');
    var signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA512(preSign, '...api_secret_hidden...').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    document.getElementById('timestamp').value = timestamp;
    document.getElementById('signature').value = signature;
</script>
```

The error I get is `401 unauthorized` in my HTTP call and also in the response of HTTP, it says `invalid_signatures`.

What am I doing wrong?